Delphi TClientDataSet (in dfm) is always active and has binary value for the Data property - how to get and edit it in design time?
I am working with the legacy code and it it has lot of TClientDataSet instances on the TDataModul or TForm children and the common feature is that many of them have:

Active=True already assigned in the design time. Of course, this property is visible in the Object Inspector.
Existing Data property with the binary value. Of course, Data property is not visible in the Object Inspector.

The problem is that I don't know how to add field to such instances in the design time. When I put Active=False and add fields just by creating new fields from field editor, then there is error message, that field is not found. I can edit dfm FieldDefs entries and save those changes, but the new fields got deleted by Delphi when I am trying to put Active=True at design time.
This is confusing? How to set Data property? How to add fields? How to put Active? I.e. how to add fields to instance that has those features?
I guess, Data property value is connected with the ability to set Active=True during design time (the code not use providers or any other design time connection to some datasets). That is why - without Data vaule I am getting error Missing data provide or data packet. If I could set this Data property, then I could enable Active=True during design time.
Additional feature - 'StoreDefs' is True and that is why - I guess - FieldDefs - are required or so.
This is legacy code - Delphi 6 (from around 2000).
Another observation added. StoreDefs is True. When I am setting it to false, then FieldDefs are erased and setting it to True, FieldDefs are recreated but in the previous way - without new field. If I set StoreDefs=False, close Delphi and reopen Delphi and set StoreDefs to True again, then FieldDefs are recreated but in the dummy way - just <>. I have no idea about benfits of StoreDefs - https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TClientDataSet.StoreDefs does not mention anything meaningful.
